# JQuery: fadeIn() does not work with appendTo()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Could you tell me why the container does not fade in and appears directly?

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

$( "a.header-chat" ).click(function() {
    $("<div class='MsgBox info'><span>asdf</span></div>").appendTo(".grid-main").hide().fadeIn(1000);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $( ".MsgBox" ).remove();
      }, 3000);
});

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try the below code.

```
$("<div class='MsgBox info'><span>asdf</span></div>").hide().appendTo(".grid-main").fadeIn(1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

$( "a.header-chat" ).click(function() {
    $("<div class='MsgBox info'><span>asdf</span></div>").hide().appendTo(".grid-main").fadeIn(1000);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $( ".MsgBox" ).remove();
      }, 3000);
});

});
```

I think working well.

Thank You

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Sorry, my fault, this works great! Used a CSS animation which sets opacity to 1.0 directly.

Comment: What's the difference in my answer and your's?